# The data that I have inputed didn't send to my database mysql

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flash, pass-by-reference

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;


    public class registration extends MovieClip {


        public function registration() {

        regbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, checkForm);

        MovieClip(root).reguser.text = "";
        MovieClip(root).regpass.text = "";

        }

        function checkForm (e:MouseEvent):void {

            if (MovieClip(root).reguser.text != "" && MovieClip(root).regpass.text != "") {

                sendForm();

            }else{

                regerr.text = "Please fill in all the fields!";

            }

        }

        function sendForm ():void {


          **/*
        we use the URLVariables class to store our php variables 
        */**

        var phpVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

        phpVars.username = reguser.text;
        phpVars.password = regpass.text;

        **/*
        we use the URLRequest method to get the address of our php file and attach the php vars.
        */**

        var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/accounts/regdb.php");

           **/*
        this attaches our php variables to the url request
        */**

        urlRequest.data = phpVars;      

        **/*
        the POST method is used here so we can use php's $_POST function in order to recieve our php variables.
        */**

        urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

        **/*
        we use the URLLoader class to send the request URLVariables to the php file
        */**

        var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

        **/*
        runs the function once the php file has spoken to flash
        */**

        urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showResultreg);

        **/*
        we send the request to the php file
        */**

        urlLoader.load(urlRequest);


    }

    **/*
    function to show result
    */**

    function showResultreg (e:Event):void {

        regerr.text = "" + e.target.data.result_message;

    }




    }

}**
```

**ERROR**
Error: Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs.
    at Error$/throwError()
    at flash.net::URLVariables/decode()
    at flash.net::URLVariables()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()

Comment: Thanks for the status report. Did you have a **question**?  [http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: i think my php file is not getting variables from flash

Comment: what it looks like is going on here is your server is responding but url loader is expecting the response to be URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES and it isn't.  Try setting the dataFormat to text and see what you get back from your server and I'll bet you can fix it from there.